# The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'. (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am stuck on this one null error, I cannot fix this error that reads "error: The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'." The error shows up at the selected: null, line. I have added my code below hopefully someone can help. Let me know if any other code is needed.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () async {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => StudyPage(
                    title: 'Add a study',
                    selected: null,
                  )));
```

*addition*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:timestudy_test/models/study.dart';
import 'package:timestudy_test/models/task.dart';
import 'package:timestudy_test/viewmodels/study_viewmodel.dart';

class StudyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final int selected;

  StudyPage({required this.title, required this.selected});

  @override
  State createState() => StudyPageState();
}

class StudyPageState extends State<StudyPage> {
  late Study study;
  late TextField nameField;
  TextEditingController nameController = new TextEditingController();
  late TextField taskNameField;
  TextEditingController taskNameController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    nameField = new TextField(
      controller: nameController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Study name'),
    );
    taskNameField = new TextField(
      controller: taskNameController,
      decoration:
      InputDecoration(labelText: 'Task name'),
    );
    if(widget.selected != null) {
      study = StudyViewModel.studies[widget.selected];
      nameController.text = study.name;
    } else {
      study = new Study(
          name: "",
          tasks: <Task>[]
      );
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    nameController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Material(
            child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0), child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0), child: nameField),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Tasks:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                title: Text('Add a task'),
                                content: taskNameField,
                                actions: <Widget>[
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: Text('Cancel'),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: Text('Accept'),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      if(taskNameController.text == ""){
                                        errorDialog(context, 'Please enter a task name!');
                                      } else {
                                        setState(() {
                                          study.tasks.add(new Task(
                                              name: taskNameController.text,
                                              elapsedTime:
                                              StudyViewModel.milliToElapsedString(
                                                  0)));
                                          taskNameController.clear();
                                        });
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            });
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: study.tasks.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(study.tasks[index].name),
                        trailing: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              study.tasks.removeAt(index);
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ), Spacer(),
                Center(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      child: Text('Save'),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (nameController.text == "") {
                          errorDialog(context, 'Please enter a study name!');
                        } else {
                          if (study.tasks.length < 1) {
                            errorDialog(context, 'Please add at least one task!');
                          } else {
                            study.name = nameController.text;
                            if (widget.selected != null) {
                              StudyViewModel.studies[widget.selected] = study;
                              await StudyViewModel.saveFile();
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            } else {
                              if (StudyViewModel.checkName(nameController.text)) {
                                errorDialog(context, 'Study name already taken!');
                              } else {
                                StudyViewModel.studies.add(study);
                                await StudyViewModel.saveFile();
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                    ))
              ],
            ),
            )));
  }

  void errorDialog(BuildContext context, String message) async {
    await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Text(message),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Close'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you should add the code of StudyPage

Comment: yes you should add the code of StudyPage Class

Comment: I have added the studypage class

Comment: You can't pass selected: null you need to send any index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant assign a value null to not Null Variable

int selected; <------- it only allow the int value such as 0,1,2,3, and goes on

if you try to pass value to this page you can check the value either it is an integer or a null value

```
int? nullableInterger;

 Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => StudyPage(
                    title: 'Add a study',
                    selected: nullableInterger ?? 0,// here 0 is const value you can chose whatever you want
                  )));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the selected argument of StudyPage as nullable. To do so

edit this code:

```dart
class StudyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final int selected;

  StudyPage({required this.title, required this.selected});

  @override
  State createState() => StudyPageState();
}
```

And change it to

```dart
class StudyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final int? selected;

  StudyPage({required this.title, required this.selected});

  @override
  State createState() => StudyPageState();
}
```

Comment: It now says error: The argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'. on the widget.selected part in the studypage class. ` if(widget.selected != null) {
      study = StudyViewModel.studies[widget.selected];
      nameController.text = study.name;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass `null` to a nonnull property

```dart
class StudyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final int selected;
.....


change to 

class StudyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final int? selected; <<<-----
```

Comment: It now says error: The argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'. on the widget.selected part in the studypage class. ` if(widget.selected != null) {
      study = StudyViewModel.studies[widget.selected];
      nameController.text = study.name;
    }`